# Generate subset combinations without duplicates?

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, subset-sum

Given a list of numbers that may have duplicate numbers, return all possible subset combinations.

If S = [2,2,2], a solution is:

[[[2], [2], [2]], [[2], [2,2]], [[2, 2, 2]]]

--- There are actually an serial of the problems, above is Split String III---

Split String

Give a string, you can choose to split the string after one character or two adjacent characters, and make the string to be composed of only one character or two characters. Output all possible results.

```
Example
Given the string "123"
return [["1","2","3"],["12","3"],["1","23"]]
```

Split String II

Give a string, you can choose to split the string after one character or any adjacent characters, and make the string to be composed of these characters. Output all possible results.

```
Example
Given the string "123"
return [['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '23'], ['12', '3'], ['123']]
```

Split String III

Give a string, you can choose to split the string after one character or any adjacent characters, and make the string to be composed of these characters. Output all possible results. String may contain duplicate numbers, reduce the duplicated results, keep them in lexicographically order.

```
Example
Given the string "222"
return [['2', '2', '2'], ['2', '22'], ['222']]
```

Comment: Most of your tags don't have anything to do with your question.

Comment: @ScottHunter, I don't think so, this is an algorithm question about dfs.

Comment: @ScottHunter basically a changed version of https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets-ii/description/

Comment: Just an idea-  you could easily predict how many duplicates exist by checking what elements themselves are duplicates. Since you iterate through all possible subsets in a procedural manner, it might be possible to derive a formula to calculate the index of a duplicate subset from the indices of the duplicate elements.

Comment: What does this have to do with a distributed file system (which is what the `dfs` tag refers to)?  Where is there computation any sum of any kind?

Comment: @ScottHunter, deep-first search.

Comment: Your code seems to produce a *smaller* set of results than desired, suggesting not removing duplicates isn't your (only) problem.

Comment: that will create a duplicate results [[2,2],[2]] and [[2],[2,2]], it will also make the algorithm to O(2^n) complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an anser for the reference, use split as mark to reduce the duplicate dfs.

```
   def subsets4(self, S):
        res = []
        split = [False for _ in range(len(S))]
        split_num = {}
        self.count = 0 
        def dfs(start_index, tmp):
            self.count += 1 
            if start_index == len(S):
                res.append(tmp)
                return 
            for i in range(start_index,len(S)):
                if (i >=2 and S[i-1] == S[i] and split[i-2] == False and split_num[S[i]] != False):
                    continue
                split[i] = True
                if S[start_index] == S[i]:
                    split_num[S[i]] = True
                dfs(i + 1, tmp + [S[start_index:i+1]])
                split_num[S[i]] = False
                split[i] = False
        S.sort()
        dfs(0, [])
        print 'dfs count:', self.count,
        return res 

>>> subsets4([2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
>>> dfs count: 20 [[[2], [2], [2], [2], [2]], [[2], [2], [2], [2, 2]], [[2], [2], [2, 2, 2]], [[2], [2, 2], [2, 2]], [[2], [2, 2, 2, 2]], [[2, 2], [2, 2, 2]], [[2, 2, 2], [2, 2]], [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]]
```

------------------Attached the split string answer as well ----------------

```
Class Solution(object):


    def splitString(self, S):
        if s is None:
            return []

        res = []
        # dfs helper to search solution for index + 1, index + 2
        def dfs(start, tmp):
            if start == len(S):
                res.append(tmp)
            end = min(start + 2, len(S))
            for i in range(start, end):
                dfs(i+1, tmp + [S[start:i+1]])

        dfs(0, [])
        return res


    def splitString2(self, S):
        if s is None:
            return []

        res = []
        # dfs helper to search solution for index + 1, index + 2
        def dfs(start, tmp):
            if start == len(S):
                res.append(tmp)
            end = len(S)
            for i in range(start, end):
                dfs(i+1, tmp + [S[start:i+1]])

        dfs(0, [])
        return res

    def splitString3(self, S):
        res = []
        split = [False for _ in range(len(S))]
        split_num = {}

        def dfs(start, tmp):
            if start == len(S):
                res.append(tmp)
                return 
            for i in range(start,len(S)):
                if (i >=2 and S[i-1] == S[i] and split[i-2] == False and split_num[S[i]] != False):
                    continue
                split[i] = True
                if S[start] == S[i]:
                    split_num[S[i]] = True
                dfs(i + 1, tmp + [S[start:i+1]])
                split_num[S[i]] = False
                split[i] = False

        dfs(0, [])
        return res
```

Comment: @ScottHunter this should be much better than O(2^n)